# View display nodes with taxonomy term found in URL

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, views

**Using Drupal 8**

I have a *working setup* my problem is when I try to access a taxonomy term that is made up of **two words.**

Set up.

- `View` : shows nodes of content type A
- Has `relationship` (required) with a field in the content type that stores the `taxonomy term` (one or more terms need to be associated to each content type)
- Has `contextual filter` (that uses previous relationship) to get the taxonomy term from the URL. The filter gets the default value from `Raw value from URL` with `Path component: 2` , and it has `Use path alias` instead of internal because the URL has the taxonomy term name. It also has `Specify validation criteria` by `Taxonomy term name` by `Transform dashes in URL to spaces in term name filter values` so that **fan-art** can be correctly matched to taxonomy term **fan art**.

I have no problem with taxonomy terms made up of one word, it's the ones made up of two words that are giving me a headache, any ideas?

Comment: These are two different terms ?? fan and art

Comment: It's just one, it's called "Fan Art", but the url for it is fan-art, it's a single Taxonomy Term.

Comment: Try term id from url option instead

Comment: It works with that just fine, I just wanted to learn why it doesn't work with the other set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up trying to understand why it doesn't work and resorted to using `Has Taxonomy term ID` instead.

- The URL contains the taxonomy term ID so *only* a **Contextual Filter** is needed. In **raw value** the URL is **taxonomy/term/[id]** , so all that needs to be done is tell the **Contextual Filter** to `Provide default value` from *Type* `Raw value from URL` and *Path Component* `3`. I also added a `Specify validation criteria` *WhenThe Filter Value is available or a default is provided*, of *Validator* `Taxonomy term ID` and chose the appropriate *Vocabulary*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this meets the requirements of your specific use case, but for anyone else who ends up here looking for something similar here it is: In the contextual filter select **'Name'** instead of **'Taxonomy Term ID'** and then check the box **'Specify validation criteria'** and select **'Taxonomy term name'** as your validator. Then check the box **'Transform dashes in URL to spaces in term name filter values'**
[image]